# How do I get a short code in India?

Tags: sms

I am developing an application that requires the use of a short code, but I can't seem to figure out where to get one. I need one in India, but when I look for one, there are plenty of companies that rent keywords to use in their short code, but I can't find anyway to get my own short code. Once again, I want my own short code, not a keyword in someone else's. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Better you contact Service providers like vodafone, Airtel, relaince...

Just by googling I came across this, May be [This](http://www.indiasms.com/products/product-display/8) be of some help